# Adding a logo in site's header

Tags: html, wordpress, graphical-logo

I would like to add a logo on my site header. Currently, on Google Chrome, it is a blank white paper. How would I go about doing so? Here is the current HTML I am using for my site header. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<title>
<?php if ( is_home() ) { ?> <?php } ?> 
<?php echo ucwords(wp_title('',true)); ?> <?php echo ucwords(get_bloginfo('name'));  ?>  
</title>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this will do,

`<link href = "images/icon.gif" rel="icon" type="image/gif">`

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you want to add a [favicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon). You can't put it in the `<title>`. [This useful tool](http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/favicon/) should help with generating an appropriate icon and give you the correct code to embed it in your site and instructions on where to add it.

Answer (score 1):

you could add the following code in the head section

```
<head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/path to your logo">
</head>
```

you have to change the logo in jpg, jpeg, gif, png into ico. you can use the 
following link for that purpose 
[link](http://www.faviconer.com/icon/import)